# VS C++ showing "C4724: potential mod by 0" and I don't know why. Compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The code looks like this:

```
class CArrayBase
    {
    protected:
        CArrayBase (HANDLE hHeap, int iGranularity);
        ~CArrayBase (void);

        int GetSize (void) const { return (m_pBlock ? m_pBlock->m_iSize : 0); }
            ***warning C4724: potential mod by 0***

        struct SHeader
            {
            HANDLE m_hHeap;             //  Heap on which block is allocated
            int m_iSize;                //  Size of data portion (as seen by callers)
            int m_iAllocSize;           //  Current size of block
            int m_iGranularity;         //  Used by descendants to resize block
            };

        SHeader *m_pBlock;

        /* Other methods omitted... */
    };
```

The full source code is here: https://github.com/kronosaur/Hexarc (see https://github.com/kronosaur/Hexarc/blob/master/Foundation/Include/FoundationArrays.h#L47)

I'm using VS 2022 (64-bit) version 17.2.1.

Here's what I've tried:

1. It only happens in Release mode.
2. C++ Language is set to C++17 Standard with Conformance mode (/permissive-). But no difference in C++14 or C++20.
3. If I change to: `int GetSize () const { return 0; }` then it compiles fine (no warning!).
4. If I change to: `int GetSize () const { return (m_pBlock ? m_pBlock->m_iSize : m_pBlock->m_iSize); }` then there is no warning.
5. If I move the definition to .cpp file it fails in the same way.
6. If I turn into an if-statement instead of ternary operator, it fails the same way (and the error is on the last line: `return 0;`).

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Clean compile - live - https://godbolt.org/z/ce76MKEcj - can you make a [mcve] ?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Erroneous-mod-by-0-warning-in-Visual-Stu/1205186

But I'm having trouble finding the place where the mod is being used. The error line points to GetSize(), but the real error is probably in a (templated) call to GetSize().

Also, I will try using size_t instead of int and see if that helps.